# Nginx не выдается index

Tags: nginx

Собственно, поменял `VDS`. Вместе со сменой `VDS` переехали и `nginx` конфиги.
На старом все работало, здесь же отказывается выдаваться `index` (возвращается код **404**).

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name yyy.xxx.ru;
    client_max_body_size 5m;
    add_header X-UA-Compatible    "IE=Edge,chrome=1";

    access_log /var/log/nginx/yyy.xxx_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/yyy.xxx_error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yyy.xxx.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yyy.xxx.ru/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    
    root /root/web/xxx/yyy;
    index index.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /info {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8013;
    }
}
```

`ls` директории `yyy`, все честно.

```
root@icyftl:~/web/xxx/yyy# ls
Server.py  css  docker-compose.yml  dockerfile  favicon.ico  fonts  img  index.html  js  
requirements.txt
```

Причем, я могу получить путь `/info`. Все выводится так, как и должно, но вот с `index`.

Comment: Читайте в error.log почему nginx решил выдать 404

Comment: @andreymal , читал access, но error не смотрел, и, похоже вы правы `"/root/web/xxx/yyy/" failed (13: Permission denied),`

Comment: @andreymal , честно, надеялся на возврат 500 в случае таких ошибок

Comment: @andreymal, а сильно плохо делать nginx user'a рутом?

Comment: Да, потому что малейший случайный косяк в nginx сразу приведёт к компрометации сервера и потому что в этом нет смысла, ведь всегда можно нормально настроить права доступа куда нужно

Comment: В частности странно класть сайты в закрытый `/root` когда их вполне можно класть в какой-нибудь открытый `/var/www` (или вообще в `/home/юзернейм/public_html` например по вкусу)

Comment: @andreymal, хм. Как то это далеко от ~. Долго писать change directory :D